# Why does JustGage display multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that saves data to a mysql database and also retrieves some variables which are displayed using the [justgage](http://justgage.com/) plugin.

For some reason which I can't figure out why, if the submit button is pressed more than once the Gauge is displayed more than once stacking above itself.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

The Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#message").hide();
    $("#myform").validate({
        submitHandler: function() {
            event.preventDefault();

            var formdata = $("#myform").serialize();
            //Post form data
            $.post('insert.php', formdata, function(data) {
                //Process post response
                //Reset Form
                $('#myform')[0].reset();
                fetchRowCount();
            });
            return false;

        }

    });


    //Fetch data from server
    function fetchRowCount() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'server.php',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#rows").html(data.rows);
                $("#min").html(data.min);
                $("#max").html(data.max);
                $("#mean").html(data.total);
                $("#last").html(data.last_entry);


                $("#your_results").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#your_data").fadeIn("slow");
                //Scroll to Gauge
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('#results').offset().top
                }, 'slow');

                //Show gage once json is receved from server

                var gage = new JustGage({
                    id: "gauge",
                    value: data.total,
                    min: data.min,
                    max: data.max,
                    title: "Sample Data"
                });

            }
        });
    }



});
```

The form

```
 <!-- Form 1-->
            <div class="form1">

                <form class="form-inline" action="" id="myform" form="" method="post">


                    <!-- Select Basic -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="type"></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">



                            <select id="type" name="type" class="form-control input-lg" required/>
                            <option value="">a</option>
                            <option value="b">b</option>
                            <option value="c">c</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="cost"></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <input id="cost" name="cost" type="text" placeholder="Cost" class="form-control input-lg" required>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Select Basic -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="location"></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <select id="location" name="location" class="form-control input-lg" required>
 <option value="" >Location</option>
      <option value="a">a</option>
      <option value="b">b</option>
      <option value="c">c</option>
    </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

               <!-- Button -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit1"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="submit" id="submitButtonId" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl" value="Submit">


                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </form>



  <div id="gauge" class="300x260px"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, why not disable the button once it has been pressed ?

Comment: You create a new `JustGage` every time. What did you expect it to do?

Comment: I tried hiding the button which worked but couldn't figure out how to show it again. I've had a lot of help with this form, my jquery knowledge is not very good.

Comment: Just to reiterate the problem. The code works fine but Gauge does not disappear and refresh when the form is submitted again, it just draws another gauge and so on. If the submit button is pressed quickly before the gauge has appeared I get multiple gauges appearing above one another. I hope that is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store a reference to the gauge outside the callback, so the same variable is used for all ajax success callbacks. Then, each time you would create a gauge, see if it was already created and just refresh it.

I also changed several `.html` to `.text`. Those appeared to be elements showing text for values, so I made it more secure by making them use `.text`, instead of `.html`.

```
var gage;    

//Fetch data from server
function fetchRowCount() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'server.php',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#rows").text(data.rows);
            $("#min").text(data.min);
            $("#max").text(data.max);
            $("#mean").text(data.total);
            $("#last").text(data.last_entry);


            $("#your_results").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#your_data").fadeIn("slow");
            //Scroll to Gauge
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#results').offset().top
            }, 'slow');

            if (!gage) {
                gage = new JustGage({
                    id: "gauge",
                    value: data.total,
                    min: data.min,
                    max: data.max,
                    title: "Sample Data"
                });
            } else {
                gage.refresh(data.total, data.max);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. This worked just how I hoped. Thank you and for the excellent explanation. The bounty will be yours!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, each time $.ajax succeed, you create a new instance of JustGage, and the JustGage add a chart in the dom $('#gauge) each time too, then it got duplicated.

You should create only one instance of JustGage, and refresh it every time when $.ajax succeed. Just like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#message").hide();
  $("#myform").validate({
    submitHandler: function() {
      event.preventDefault();

      var formdata = $("#myform").serialize();
      //Post form data
      $.post('insert.php', formdata, function(data) {
        //Process post response
        //Reset Form
        $('#myform')[0].reset();
        fetchRowCount();
      });
      return false;
    }
  });

  var gage = new JustGage({
    id: "gauge",
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    title: "Sample Data"
  });

  //Fetch data from server
  function fetchRowCount() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'server.php',
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        $("#rows").html(data.rows);
        $("#min").html(data.min);
        $("#max").html(data.max);
        $("#mean").html(data.total);
        $("#last").html(data.last_entry);


        $("#your_results").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#your_data").fadeIn("slow");
        //Scroll to Gauge
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#results').offset().top
        }, 'slow');

        // Refresh gage once json is receved from server
        gage.refresh(data.total, data.max, {min: data.min});
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Usage of [JustGage.prototype.refresh](https://github.com/toorshia/justgage/blob/master/justgage.js#L860)